# Google Script send form values by email, error: Cannot read property "Timestamp" from undefined/Cannot read property "0" from undefined

Tags: javascript

Google Script send form values by email, error: Cannot read property "Timestamp" from undefined/Cannot read property "0" from undefined.
I add two options with two bugs, the script receive the info from exel file.
the code is below:

```
    function sendFormByEmail(e) {
    var Subject = "Subject";
    var Email = "email";
    var Key = "keynumber";
    var Editors = 0;
    var extraColumns = 8;

    if (useEditors) {
        var editors = DocsList.getFileById(Key).getEditors();
        if (editors) {
            var notify = editors.join(',');
        } else var notify = Email;
    } else {
        var notify = Email;
    }

    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
    if (extraColumns) {
        var headers = s.getRange(1, 1, 1, extraColumns).getValues()[0];
    } else var headers = s.getRange(1, 1, 1, s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];

    var message = "";
    for (var i in headers) {
        //First case:
        // message += headers[i] + ' = '+ s.namedValues[headers[i]].toString() + "\n\n";   
        //var i is "Timestamp"  
        //TypeError: Cannot read property "Timestamp" from undefined.
        //Second case:
        message += headers[i] + ' = ' + s.values[i].toString() + '\n\n'; 
        //TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined.

    }
    MailApp.sendEmail(notify, Subject, message);
}
```

I have the following two errors in first and second types: 
1)TypeError: Cannot read property "Timestamp" from undefined
2)TypeError: Cannot read property "0" from undefined.
What is my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are trying to access a non existing properties, and it seems that [Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) object doesn't contain `namedValues` or `values` properties, if you want to add all cells to message variable, try this:

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");

if (extraColumns) {
    var values = s.getRange(1, 1, s.getLastRow(), extraColumns).getValues();
} else {
    var values = s.getRange(1, 1, s.getLastRow(), s.getLastColumn()).getValues();
}

var message = "";
for (var i=1; i < values.length; i++) { 

    for (var j=0; j < values[i].length; j++) {
        message += values[0][j] + ' = ' + values[i][j] + '\n\n'; 
    }

}
```

**Edit** add only the last row to message variable:

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");

if (extraColumns) {
    var values = s.getRange(1, 1, s.getLastRow(), extraColumns).getValues();
} else {
    var values = s.getRange(1, 1, s.getLastRow(), s.getLastColumn()).getValues();
}

var message = "";
var lastRow = values.length-1;

for (var j=0; j < values[lastRow].length; j++) {
    message += values[0][j] + ' = ' + values[lastRow][j] + '\n\n'; 
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have 7 columns and 38 strings.My Headers -  Timestamp, referring URL, user agent, requested URL, requested host,Email,Email Address,email - Every Header has 38 strings,  I can't do it one by one, how can I send all data from excel column by column?

Comment: Is there a specific column  you want to get its value ? or you want to add all column values to message variable ?

Comment: it is Array: ["Timestamp", "referring URL", "user agent", "requested URL", "requested host", "Email", "Email Address", "email"]

Comment: Yes I want add all columns and all values to message.

Comment: How can I add all column values to message variable ?

Comment: Sorry but where are the Headers in Your answers?

Comment: You are welcome, you may want to accept my answer :)

Comment: I can accept in stackoverflow? Or do You mean at all? If I will have a question in a future, may I ask You In any way?

Comment: Yes you can accept the answer that works for you, here is the [tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get an idea how stackoverflow works,

Comment: Accepting an answer could help other people that have the same issue, if you have a question just put it in stackoverflow and all the community is here to help

Comment: Ok, Where I can find the accept link? One more question to You, How can I Output just the last line and not the whole lines like I asked You?

Comment: The accept button is green on the left side of my answer, if you want to loop over the last just fix i to 37 and remove the first `for` loop (that's because you said you have 38 row from 0 to 37)

Comment: I can't use number if I want last line because the number of lines will grow up, I mean tommorow 38,39 e.t.c. so I need leave it dinamic just last line can I do it?

Comment: It’s simple just do values[values.length-1][j] to get the last row value under column number j, plz mark my answer as accepted, as i said there is a button on the left side of my answer the green one you can click on it if you think my answer was helpful for you.

Comment: I try but I can't see one button green on the page will be it is not allowed for me?

Comment: I find it and accepted it was not green, it become green "V" after I accepted it. So I should do  for (var j=0; j < values[values.length-1][j]; j++) {
        message += values[values.length-1][j] + ' = ' + values[values.length-1][j] + '\n\n';  right? 
    }

Comment: No it’s ‘for(var j=0; j<values[values.length-1]; j++) { message += values[0][j] + ‘ = ‘ + values[values.length-1][j] + ‘\n\n’; }’

Comment: Will be the problem with  values[values.length-1][j]?

Comment: The question is to output just the last string what updated or add last.

Comment: Hmm maybe you have to store `values.length-1` in a variable and then use it inside loop, can you please show me the whole error text that you have

Comment: It is just red area with text: Illegal character. line 43. and line 43 it is the code You send me. I can't understand, the code before for all strings working very well. when \I remove the values.length-1 and put "i", so the mail send but empty.

Comment: I tried  var values2 = values.length-1;
  for(var j=0; j < values[values2]; j++) 
 { 
   message += values[0][j] + ‘ = ‘ + values[values2][j] + ‘\n\n; 
   
 } but no changes : Illegal character. (строка 44, File Code)

Comment: var message = "";
for (var i=1; i < values.length; i++) { 

 for(var j=0; j < values[values.length-1]; j++) 
 { 
   message += values[0][j] + ‘ = ‘ + values[values.length-1][j] + ‘\n\n; 
   
 }

}

Comment: Oh sorry i forget to add length property in for condition: `for(var j=0; j<values[values.length-1].length; j++) { message += values[0][j] + ‘ = ‘ + values[values.length-1][j] + ‘\n\n’; }`

Comment: var message = "";
for (var i=1; i < values.length; i++) { 
  for(var j=0; j<values[values.length-1].length; j++) 
  { 
    message += values[0][j] + ‘ = ‘ + values[values.length-1][j] + ‘\n\n’; 
  }

}
Same Error in string -     message += values[0][j] + ‘ = ‘ + values[values.length-1][j] + ‘\n\n’;

Comment: You don't need to use the first loop: `var message = ""; for(var j=0; j<values[values.length-1].length; j++) { message += values[0][j] + ‘ = ‘ + values[values.length-1][j] + ‘\n\n’; }`

Comment: But same error in same line - message += values[0][j] + ‘ = ‘ + values[values.length-1][j] + ‘\n\n’;

Comment: I updated my answer, and plz remove your answer because it's not allowed by stackoverflow, answer's area should contain solution not a question

Comment: As I understand I should remove loop with i (the first loop) and it is my code: var message = ""; for(var j=0; j<values[values.length-1].length; j++) { message += values[0][j] + ‘ = ‘ + values[values.length-1][j] + ‘\n\n’; } and I receive same error. will be exist another way?

Comment: Will exist another way output just last string?

Comment: Can I read the number of the strings and get the last for output?

Comment: Sorry YouneL I see the changes whole Your edited answer and it is working for me with lat string.